# Record Iframe network call using selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cdp

I want to record iframe network calls using selenium CDP api . I am using selenium network interceptor to record website network call but unable to record for iframes .

I have already tried to disable features like IsolateOrigins,site-per-process but that didn't help

Comment: Please describe a bit more detailed what you have tried, what result you expect and what your failed attempts produced.